# 'clang -ftime-trace' does not produce a JSON file

Tags: c++, clang, build-time

Clang supports the [`-ftime-trace` flag](https://github.com/aras-p/llvm-project-20170507/pull/2) since [version 9](https://releases.llvm.org/9.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#new-compiler-flags) which allows to analyze compilation times by producing a JSON file that can be read by Google Chrome. Unfortunately, Clang fails to output a JSON file for me, even for the simplest program.

Minimal example: I have a `main.cpp` file

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;
}
```

Using Clang 13 (on [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) with [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa))) and compiling it with `clang++ -ftime-trace main.cpp` produces the executable `a.out`, but no JSON file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [-ftime-trace](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-ftime-trace) flag produces JSON files for each object file and places them next to each object file. It does not profile the linking stage.

Running `clang++ -ftime-trace main.cpp` produces a temporary object file in the `/tmp/` directory and then runs the linker to form the complete executable `a.out` in your working directory. Thus, if you look into the `/tmp/` directory, you can actually find your JSON file there.

Simply specify the [-c](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-c) flag, i.e., `clang++ -ftime-trace -c main.cpp`, to skip the linker and produce an object file `main.o` along the JSON  file `main.json` in your working directory. You can also provide a different name for these files using the [-o](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang1-o-file) flag.